Repetition of already guessed letter upon displaying already guessed letter in python
In my code when I run this and for example if the word is run then if you type for example "r" and then the same letter, "r", again in the next input box it will print that "r" is already guessed" for every letter of chosen_word.
import random
from hangman_words import word_list
from hangman_art import logo
from hangman_art import stages
# TODO-1: - Update the word list to use the 'word_list' from hangman_words.py

lives = 6

# TODO-3: - Import the logo from hangman_art.py and print it at the start of the game.

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
print(logo)
print(chosen_word)

placeholder = ""
word_length = len(chosen_word)
for position in range(word_length):
    placeholder += "_"
print("Word to guess: " + placeholder)

game_over = False
correct_letters = []

while not game_over:

    # TODO-6: - Update the code below to tell the user how many lives they have left.
    print(f"**************************** {lives} /6 LIVES LEFT****************************")
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

    # TODO-4: - If the user has entered a letter they've already guessed, print the letter and let them know.


    # Relevant part:
    display = ""

    for letter in chosen_word:
        if letter == guess:
            display += letter
            correct_letters.append(guess)
        elif letter in correct_letters:
            display += letter
        else:
            display += "_"
        if guess in display:
            print(f"You've already guessed {guess}!")
    print("Word to guess: " + display)


    # TODO-5: - If the letter is not in the chosen_word, print out the letter and let them know it's not in the word.
    #  e.g. You guessed d, that's not in the word. You lose a life.

    if guess not in chosen_word:
        lives -= 1

        if lives == 0:
            game_over = True

            # TODO 7: - Update the print statement below to give the user the correct word they were trying to guess.
            print(f"***********************YOU LOSE**********************")

    if "_" not in display:
        game_over = True
        print("****************************YOU WIN****************************")

    # TODO-2: - Update the code below to use the stages List from the file hangman_art.py
    print(stages[lives])

I tried making it so that my code would output for example: If I enter "r" for the second time in the word "run" then it would say you have already guess "r" but instead its multplying it by the length of the word "run".
The used hangman library can be found here.

Create an additional variable to store already given guesses and check if the new guess is in it (and print message if so) before the for-loop.

You are checking, if the letter was already guessed within the loop, so it will be repeated for every letter of the word starting from the first occurrence of the letter.
In the example "run", entering "r" twice will print the message three times. For words like "overflow" it will be printed five times, because for the first three letters this condition is not met: guess in display
To prevent the message from being printed more than once, you can just move the block out of the for loop and the logic remains the same as it doesn't rely on letter:
display = ""

for letter in chosen_word:
    if letter == guess:
        display += letter
        correct_letters.append(guess)
    elif letter in correct_letters:
        display += letter
    else:
        display += "_"

if guess in display:
    print(f"You've already guessed {guess}!")


But this won't work with letters, that are not in the word. To keep track of the guessed letters you can define a variable before the main loop:
guessed_letters = set()

This makes use of a set, which is similar to a list but is unordered and can't have duplicate entries.
Inside the loop you can just check if the guess is in this set:
if guess in guessed_letters:
    print(f"You've already guessed {guess}!")
else:
    guessed_lettters.add(guess)


It would have been good if you mentioned from where we could get the hangman relevant .py libraries which can be found here. here are the corrected codes. you simply needed to introduce condition if guess == displaying letters in a separate for loop before the main for loop takes action and then after make display empty again by display = "".
import random
from hangman_words import word_list
from hangman_art import logo
from hangman_art import stages

# TODO-1: - Update the word list to use the 'word_list' from hangman_words.py

lives = 6

# TODO-3: - Import the logo from hangman_art.py and print it at the start of the game.

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
print(logo)
print(chosen_word)
print('=============================')
print(f"type QUIT to exit the game")
print(f"type HINT to receive a hint")
print('=============================')
placeholder = ""
word_length = len(chosen_word)
for position in range(word_length):
    placeholder += "_"
print("Word to guess: " + placeholder)

game_over = False
quit = False
correct_letters = []
display = ""


# for hints, returning a not displayed correct letter
def hint(str1,str2): # str1 and str2 are correct letters and chosen word
    str1 = "".join(str1) # making sure all letters are into a single word
    str2 = "".join(str2)
    str1 = str(str1) # making sure they are strings
    str2 = str(str2)
    notdisplayed = []
    set1 = set(list(str1))
    set2 = set(list(str2))
    setout = set1 & set2
    setout = list(setout)
    wholeset = str1 + str2
    for s in wholeset:
        if s not in setout:
            notdisplayed.append(s)        
    
    return random.choice(notdisplayed)

while not game_over and not quit:

    # TODO-6: - Update the code below to tell the user how many lives they have left.
    print(f"**************************** {lives} /6 LIVES LEFT****************************")
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    if guess == 'quit':
        quit = True
    if guess == 'hint':
        guess = hint(correct_letters, chosen_word)
        print('hint is', guess)
    # TODO-4: - If the user has entered a letter they've already guessed, print the letter and let them know.

    for letter_ in display:
        if letter_ == guess:
            print(f"You've already guessed {guess}!")
            break
    display = ""    
    for letter in chosen_word:
        if letter == guess:
            display += letter
            correct_letters.append(guess)
        elif letter in correct_letters:
            display += letter
        else:
            display += "_"
    print("Word to guess: " + display)
    

    # TODO-5: - If the letter is not in the chosen_word, print out the letter and let them know it's not in the word.
    #  e.g. You guessed d, that's not in the word. You lose a life.

    if guess not in chosen_word:
        lives -= 1

        if lives == 0:
            game_over = True

            # TODO 7: - Update the print statement below to give the user the correct word they were trying to guess.
            print(f"***********************YOU LOSE**********************")

    if "_" not in display:
        game_over = True
        print("****************************YOU WIN****************************")

    # TODO-2: - Update the code below to use the stages List from the file hangman_art.py
    print(stages[lives])

I also added option quit and hint. typing quit simply exit the game while hint reveals a right letter. you can easily limit number of hints by a little modification if you want to distress players a bit. Don't forget to hide print(chosen_word) when your tests are done. happy playing!!
